# Firebase: How to check if users phone is already verified and signin automatically?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, firebase

I Wonder how we can check if user is already verified in firebase so we just can signin the user immediately when user opens app? Also I wonder if we can KEEP user signed in after first sign in?

I try to get user-id like this, to check if user is verified or not:

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil
```

So, my plan is `if currentUser != nil`, I'll send him to mainActivity. But it don't work. Even if there is a value in "Auth.currUser", this method don't trigger. I don't know what's wrong?

Comment: mainActivity on iOS?!

Comment: No, MainController e.g. Profile/Whatever you would've set as main-UI. Don't be such a fool, you look like a very experienced developer, and I'm sure you understood what I meant.

Comment: I did indeed. I just wanted to point out the mistake. You should be clear and precise in your use of terminology to avoid any unclarity. Did not want to offend in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [authentication state listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start#listen_for_authentication_state) to find out if and when there is a user signed in, then do what you want in the listener.

Comment: Thanks! I Wonder how I can move to another controller if user is signed in. Neither "self.performSegue" OR self.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) will work for me!? I'm so frustrated.. the app keeps moving to login page even if user is signed in?

Comment: Great, so I fixed it! There is a huge bug in the swift xcode shitty shit. If anyone else experience problems moving between Controllers, ADD THIS: OperationQueue.main.addOperation{ *storyboard, secondViewController, present* } and it should work like a charm!